# How to check security strength of random k if k is an input parameter of ECDSA signature generation function using openssl-fips

Tags: random-number-generator

As I understand,

1.The security strength is specified in bits according to https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1.pdf

2.Security strength is depend on the length of entropy input when generating random number

So, in the signature generation function, if the random k is an input parameter (not generate random k in this function)

How to check valid k? security strength of random k?

1, Only check number of bits of random k ?

2, Other testing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In the [standard definition of ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1), the nonce $k$ should be a secret uniformly random integer in range $[1,n)$, where $n$ is the prime order of the generator. Analysis of message/signature pairs when $k$ is known, or has a defect (such as a bias, or a tendency to repeat) can leak the private key, thus generation of $k$ matters to security.

It is not possible for an implementation of ECDSA signature generation to meaningfully check that the value of an *input* $k$ it receives is suitable for safe use *as prescribed* in the [standard definition of ECDSA signature](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.4.1.3), because there is not way to tell from a value if it is secret or not, which is a most essential quality $k$ should possess. It's also impossible to assess if a given $k$ is random as the question suggests, at least unless we know how it was produced. And anyway, in the context, being random is secondary to being secret.

Therefore, rather than accepting $k$ as an input, common procedure is to make the generation of a random $k$ part of the implementation of ECDSA signature generation. A basic (if not necessarily recommendable) procedure is to draw $\lceil\log_2(n)\rceil$ bits from an assumed cryptographically strong RNG (such as `/dev/urandom`) and interpret these bits as an integer $k$ per e.g. big-endian convention, until it holds $0<k<n$ (which for many $n$ used in practice is essentially always, because $n$ is just below a power of two). I disregard this basic procedure in the rest of the answer (even though this [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/209406) suggests that was the meat of the question).

It is possible to modify the ECDSA signature generation procedure to safely use whatever $k$ it receives. Instead of $k$, the signature generation can use $k':=f(d_U,H,k)$ where $d_U$ is the private key, $H$ is the hash of the message to sign, and $f$ is a public key derivation function using $d_U$ as master key, with output close to uniform in $[1,n)$ where $n$ is the order of the generator. Such practice does not break compatibility in any way, and is only detectable with both $k$ and the private key (on top of other public information). For $n$ up to 384-bit at least, a suitable function would be $$k':=1+(\operatorname{HMAC-SHA-512}(d_U,H\mathbin\|k)\bmod(n-1))$$

Note: in theory, the signing procedure has a number of "return to Step 1" which will re-invoke $f$ and expect a different $k'$, and won't get that. However that's moot, since the likelihood of re-invocation of $f$ is entirely negligible, and not testable even with control of $d_U$, $H$ and $k$, for proper fixed non-malignant $f$. If that possibility nevertheless prevents a rubber stamp from hitting the paper, we could use $k'=f(d_U,H\oplus j,k)$ where $j$ is the number of previous invocations of $f$ in the signature.

Note: when and if there is no drawback in making the signature deterministic, we can ignore the input $k$. When considering some (but far from all) side-channel attacks that may even be safer, in particular against attacks by adversaries that know and control $k$.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your explanation ! So, If k is from TRNG (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator), Knowing how it was produced. Is my 1st solution still possible? which is only check number of bits of k. Assume that, k (from TRNG) are secret and random

Comment: @Andy: I have expanded on the basic (if not recommendable) way to generate $k$ in ECDSA, see third paragraph of the answer. Note that if you use an existing implementation of ECDSA signature, likely it generates $k$ (and if it cares about security it might use a technique similar to the one I describe in the fourth paragraph). Beware that there are many difficulties in making a secure implementation of ECDSA signature generation (side channels, fault attacks..), and common wisdom is that it should be left to experienced security programmers.